# How to obtain navbar child component state in parent App.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

TL;DR: I'd like to pass click result from Navbar component to its parent App component.

I have a `Navbar.js` which is rendered in `App.js`, and the navbar has several tabs on it. In `App.js` there are also several `Card.js` component rendered based on click event on the navbar, e.g. a user clicks 'Food' on navbar, `App.js` should show all 'Food' cards. Now in `App.js`, I'd like to know which tab has been clicked on navbar. Here are some code:

Navbar.js (the child component)

```
class Navbar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {currentTab: null};
    this.findTab = this.findTab.bind(this);
  }
  findTab(){
    this.setState({currentTab: 'Food'}) // here onClick the state of navbar is set to 'Food'
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <Navbar>
        <Navbar.item onClick={() => this.findTab(tab)}>
        </Navbar.item>
      </Navbar>
    )
  }
}
```

App.js (the parent component):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {currentCategory: null};
    this.renderCards = this.rendercards.bind(this);
  }
  renderCards(){
    const category = 'Food' // here I need to know on Navbar.item, user clicked and set the state to 'Food', so I can make category = 'Food'
    this.setState({currentCategory: category});
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <Navbar />
      <Card currentCategory={this.state.currentCategory} />
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see I have made the `Navbar.js` state to 'Food' on click, I'm not sure if this is the correct way to pass data to its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, As per my understanding this situation can be easily handled by simply passing **renderCards()** as props in Navbar.js component.

For more details on props and how to use them please go through the Reactjs docs.
[Components and props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Below are the changes you need to do to achieve **App.js** render right card.

In **Navbar.js** 
you have to take use **this.props.renderCards('Food')** Onclick. In place of 'Food' you can pass diffrent categories.

```
class Navbar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {currentTab: null};
    this.findTab = this.findTab.bind(this);
  }
//we do not need findTab method to achieve your renderCard().
  findTab(){
    this.setState({currentTab: 'Food'}) // here onClick the state of navbar is set to 'Food'
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <Navbar>
        <Navbar.item onClick={() => this.props.renderCards('Food')}>
        </Navbar.item>
      </Navbar>
    )
  }
}
```

In **App.js**

You Pass the **this.renderCards()** as props in **Navbar** component.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {currentCategory: null};
    this.renderCards = this.rendercards.bind(this);
  }
  renderCards(category){
  // here we will get the actual category as a parameter of the method.
    this.setState({currentCategory: category});
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <Navbar renderCards={this.renderCards} />
      <Card currentCategory={this.state.currentCategory} />
    )
  }
}
```

Summary: props are the best way to pass the data from child to parent or parent to child.

Comment: Thank you! You are correct, I only knew props can pass data from parent component to child, didn't know it could pass from child to parent too.